# Change of status from an F-1 to B -1/ B-2

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

Is it possible to change a USA F-1 visa for B -1/B-2 visa because of a change of interest?

Comment: You cannot "swap" them out; you'd have to apply for a B1/B2 separately as there are different requirements for each.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that is incorrect; see my answer for more information.

Comment: The person is asking about a visa not change of status.

Comment: Are you already in the US?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid many people confuse the two.  I think Karlson has hit the nail on the head: I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that the OP is already in the US.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you can change your status, but you won't actually get a new visa.  You'll need to file form I-539, Application To Extend/Change Nonimmigrant Status: http://www.uscis.gov/i-539.

This assumes you are already in the US, as Karlson point out in a comment to your question.  If you are not in the US, you will probably have to file a new application.  Ask at the consulate.  They will be able to tell you.  Surely this has happened before.